# How to react to changes in two tables with Kotlin Flow and Android Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, reactive-programming, kotlin-flow

I have two simple tables.

| ProductId | Brand | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... | ... |

| ProductId | Favourite | ShoppingList |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | true |
| 3 | true | false |

The first table stores the data coming from an API.
For the second table the user can mark and unmark products as favourites or as products added to the shopping list.

The interface displays the data from both tables in a list.

I would like to know if this structure is the most suitable and also how can I use Kotlin Flows to react to changes in both tables.  Firstly, to refresh my screen when new products come from the API and, secondly, when the user bookmarks or adds to the shopping list.

Initially I chose to have a single table with all the necessary fields but this becomes difficult to maintain when mixing user preferences with the generic product listing.

Comment: You can use the return amount that you get in the Dao.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can handle this with a @RawQuery as follows:

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [TableA::class, TableB::class])
```

Of coarse, with the RawQuery Room isn't going to do any validation on your query.